# when i use setHomeButtonEnabled(true) theApp Icon is not clickable

Tags: android

when i set "setHomeButtonEnabled(true)",  but app Icon  is not clickable  on emulator . i want to know  whay  this icon  can not  work?

next  is the  Main2Activity file

```
    package com.example.laoban.newtext;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    private TextView txt;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem mi)
    {
        if(mi.isChecked())
        {
            mi.setChecked(true);
        }
        switch(mi.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Log.d("Main2Activity","actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled");
                txt.setText("哈哈");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void show(View source)
    {
        actionBar.show();

    }
    public void hide(View source)
    {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
}
```

this is the mainfest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

please help me i will pay for you

Comment: 1.) Does it log anything when you click on the home button? 2.) Did you try putting 'return true;' inside the 'case android.R.id.home' block instead of 'break;'?

Comment: Have you tried without putting **哈哈** ?

Comment: can you please share styles.xml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`
2. Try using `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.
3. Use any `AppCompat` theme (Ex. `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`)

**Here is the working code. Try this:**

**Main2Activity.java:**

```
package com.example.laoban.newtext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txt;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem mi)
    {
        if(mi.isChecked())
        {
            mi.setChecked(true);
        }
        switch(mi.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Log.d("Main2Activity","actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled");
                txt.setText("哈哈");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void show(View source)
    {
        actionBar.show();

    }
    public void hide(View source)
    {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
}
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]